# Which pointer-events value of SVG should be used for a specific scernario

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

There are two rectangles in a svg with ids - "blue" and "transparent". The transparent
reactangle is above the blue.

```
<svg width="1000" height="1000">
  <rect id="blue"   x="150" y="0" width="100" height="300" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  <rect id="transparent" pointer-events="visible" x="100" y="100" width="300" height="100" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

[image]

I have associated the mouse-over event of the transparent rectangle to display a
tooltip text, say "Transparent". Now I have a requirement that when the user mouse-overs
the transparent rectangle the event should be executed on the transparent rectangle but when
the user clicks the intersecting region between the transparent and blue rectangle the events
associated with the blue rect should be executed.

If I make the pointer-events="visiblePainted" for the transparent rectangle none of the events for
the transparent rectangle(I want to capture mouse-over event) are captured and the blue reactangle
below captures all the events. Is there any way to specify allowing move-over events after making
pointer-events="visiblePainted" for the transparent rectangle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointer-events painted for transparent rect,

```js
document.getElementById('transparent').addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  console.log('transparent');
});

document.getElementById('blue').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('blue');
});
```

```html
<svg width="1000" height="1000">
  <rect id="blue"   x="150" y="0" width="100" height="300" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  <rect id="transparent" pointer-events="painted" x="100" y="100" width="300" height="100" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can only be achieved with Javascript. The mouse event is either captured by one element or the other, intersections are not detectable with CSS.

The procedure is a bit cumbersome:

- detect the position of the mouse event in screen coordinates
- transform them to local coordinates of the blue rect
- test if the point is both inside the fill or stroke of the blue rect
- react accordingly

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const blue = document.querySelector('#blue');

function onBlueClick () {
    console.log('Blue clicked!')
}
blue.addEventListener('click', onBlueClick)

document.querySelector('#transparent').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const transform = blue.getScreenCTM().inverse();
    const cursor = svg.createSVGPoint();
    cursor.x = event.clientX;
    cursor.y = event.clientY;

    const point = cursor.matrixTransform(transform);
    if (blue.isPointInFill(point) || blue.isPointInStroke(point)) {
        onBlueClick();
    }
});
```

```html
<svg width="1000" height="1000">
  <rect id="blue"   x="150" y="0" width="100" height="300" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
    <title>Transparent</title>
  </rect>
  <rect id="transparent" pointer-events="visible" x="100" y="100" width="300" height="100" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```